# At build, maven shall call spring-boot-maven-plugin at steps 1 and 3. Can I avoid the warning "found duplicate declaration of plugin"?

Tags: maven

I have a *Maven* build that has three steps :

1. **spring-boot-maven-plugin** : starts my application at the beginning of `integration-test`, stop it at the end of `integration-test`.
2. *springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin* : Asks *OpenAPI* (= *Swagger*) to generate `yaml` files from REST methods existing in my application during `integration-test`.
3. **spring-boot-maven-plugin** : creates the executable fat jar of the `spring-boot` application.

```xml
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>start</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            
            <execution>
                <id>post-integration-test</id>
                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>stop</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        
        <configuration> 
            <apiDocsUrl>http://localhost:9090/v3/api-docs</apiDocsUrl> 
            <outputFileName>openapi.json</outputFileName> 
            <outputDir>${project.build.directory}/openapi</outputDir> 
        </configuration>                
    </plugin>       
 
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>repackage</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        
        <configuration>
            <executable>true</executable>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

`spring-boot-maven-plugin` is called two times, not in the same *Maven* phase, and a "foreign" maven plugin is used between the callings.

Is there a way I can avoid the warnings about the duplication of the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` plugin ?

```
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for fr.comptes.france:application-metier-et-gestion:jar:0.0.6-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.(groupId:artifactId)' must be unique but found duplicate declaration of plugin org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin @ line 191, column 12
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
```

Comment: Why do you like to start your application via build as an integration test? You could use @SpringBootTest etc. instead. The question is what kind of integration test you are writing which can not be handled by using @SpringBootTest?

Comment: @khmarbaise Oh yes. It's tricky, sorry! in fact, the `integration-test` here isn't really an integration test ! It's goal is to start the application at build time, to allow it to become the server that the _OpenAPI_ tool needs to generate a `yaml` file describing its REST services. Later the clients of my application will use this `yaml` file to build their accesses to it's REST services.

Comment: As far as I know this is also possible via integration tests...  see for example https://dzone.com/articles/openapi-3-documentation-with-spring-boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never declare a plugin twice.

Instead, define different executions in the plugin definition. These execution may be in different phases.

Answer (score 0):

@JFabianMeier : Yes. Eventually, I succeeded by reformulating the `spring-boot-maven plugin` flow of executions :

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

    <executions>
        <!-- Démarrer l'application en intégration -->
        <execution>
            <id>pre-integration-test</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        
        <!-- Provoquer la génération yaml par OpenApi des services REST -->
        <execution>
            <id>post-integration-test</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        
        <!-- Créer le fat jar exécutable de l'application -->
        <execution>
            <id>executable-jar</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
            
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```